# Extract multiple parts of a string based on three set formats

Tags: r, string

I was curious if there is a simple way to extract multiple parts of a string based on possible different formats. I want to be able to pass in a vector of strings that are either of the form 'x >= a', 'x <= b', or 'a <= x <= b'. The variable x should be able to vary to be any variable name and a and b will have to  be numeric values

Ideally it would be a function that would produce the following data frame as a result, given I passed in the *cons* string variable.

```
              cons lower_bound variable upper_bound
1           x >= 1           1        x          NA
2         s <= 100          NA        s         100
3 0 <= beta <= 500           0     beta         500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as long as the `cons` entries are consistently formatted:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  tibble(
    cons = c("x >= 1", "s <= 100", "0 <= beta <= 500")
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(
    lower_bound = case_when(
      str_detect(cons, ">=") ~ str_extract(cons, "\\d+$"),
      str_detect(cons, "<=(.)+<=") ~ str_extract(cons, "^\\d+"),
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    ),
    variable = str_extract(cons, "[a-z]+"),
    upper_bound = case_when(
      str_detect(cons, "<=") ~ str_extract(cons, "\\d+$"),
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  cons             lower_bound variable upper_bound
  <chr>            <chr>       <chr>    <chr>      
1 x >= 1           1           x        NA         
2 s <= 100         NA          s        100        
3 0 <= beta <= 500 0           beta     500
```